# Module Structure Python + Django, No module named 'entities'

Tags: python, django

See the picture below for my project structure.

In riskgame/view.py I tried to reach the entity Risk.py:

```
from entities.Risk import Risk

def index(request):
     game = Risk()

return HttpResponse("test")
```

When I tried this I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'entities'`
"

Also from `api.risk.riskgame.entities.Risk import Risk` I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'`

What is a good structure for my project?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from riskgame.entities.Risk import Risk`

or

`from .entities.Risk import Risk`

Comment: What kind of name should I use in the INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: I found what was wrong..

You should have imported 

`from riskgame.entities.Risk import Risk`

Comment: Thanks!, this + assign a new source folder in Pycharm solved the problem